# How do I disable a kernel module persistently?

Tags: kernel-modules, modprobe

So I had this problem with my new Lenovo ThinkPad 13 where it did not resume from suspension and hibernation. After 2 days of troubleshooting I found out that apparently a module called intel_lpss_pci is causing the problem. When I disable it, everything works fine. I'm not exactly sure what it is used for too, as everything seems to be working just fine without it.

Now to my question. How can I disable this module for good?

I tried the kernel parameter `modprobe.blacklist=intel_lpss_pci` which didn't seem to do the trick and also adding it to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` did not seem to work.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: i'll try that right now!

Comment: @jimmij This did the trick! Thank you my friend. If you'd answer the question officially I could vote it as accepted

Comment: did you have an existing `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` file or did you create it from scratch?  I ask because i'm interested in knowing if `blacklist` versus `blacklist.conf` is a distribution specific syntax.

Comment: @ron I did create it myself

Comment: it's interesting how it's always the little things.  I use Suse/SLES and the file is `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`  without the conf suffix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper file is:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

(notice the extension `.conf`). And at the end of this file put a line:

```
blacklist intel_lpss_pci
```